# How to get rid of black rectangle layout guides in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, guides

How do I get rid of these annoying black rectangles in After Effects?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a button at the bottom of the Composition view that lets you toggle visibility of a bunch of different guides & grids.

"Title/Action Safe" toggles the safe zones.

You can also <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> that button to toggle the safe zones on and off without having to bring up the dropdown menu.

[image: Composition Panel Guides]

Answer (score 0):

Those are safe-zone outline, shows how much of your view port is actually be seen in the real life TV or Other media. It doesn't stay in the rendered file. Hope you will get used to them. It helps a lot.

To change settings for safe-zone margins, grids, and guides, choose Edit > Preferences > Grids & Guides (Windows) or After Effects > Preferences > Grids & Guides (Mac OS).

u can find more details [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/modifying-using-views.html)